# Which DirichletCharacter is KroneckerSymbol?

Tags: number-theory

If $d$ is a fundamental discriminant, `KroneckerSymbol[d,n]` is a Dirichlet character modulo $|d|$.  *Which one is it?*  If $d>0$ is a prime $\equiv 1\bmod 4$, then it's `DirichletCharacter[d,(d+1)/2,n]`, and similarly if $d<0$, with prime $-d\equiv 3\bmod 4$ it is `DirichletCharacter[-d,(1-d)/2,n]`.

In general, there is a function which, on input a fundamental discriminant $d$ outputs $j$ such that `KroneckerSymbol[d,n]` is equal to `DirichletCharacter[Abs[d],j,n]` for all $n$ relatively prime to $|d|$.  The ability to compute such $j$ easily would allow one to use the built in `DirichletL` to compute the Dirichlet series attached to the Kronecker symbol.

Of course one can build a table of values of `KroneckerSymbol[d,n]` and of all `DirichletCharacter[Abs[d],k,n]` for k=1,2,... `EulerPhi[Abs[d]]`, and then look for a match.  I'm looking for something smarter and more efficient than that, for use with large composite d.

Comment: I think the thing that confuses me, being a long way removed from number theory, is that you seem to answer your own question?  Or are you looking for something like `DirichletCharacter[Abs[d], (1 + Abs[d])/2, n]`?

Comment: A warning note for anyone working on this. The documentation for `DirichletCharacter[]` (version 8) reads "Real Dirichlet characters modulo $k$ have index $1$ or $\phi(k)/2+1$." THIS IS FALSE. There are $4$ Dirichlet characters modulo $8$ and all of them are real. It looks like the true statement is that the Dirichlet characters of index $1$ and $\phi(k)/2+1$ are real, but so are some other ones. (Run `Table[DirichletCharacter[8, j, Range[8]], {j, 1, 4}]` if you'd like to see for yourself.)

Comment: Does [this](http://wolfram.com/xid/0hyvexhtj8dm5maa-b3ac5m) help? (It's documentation from version 9. A colleague suggested it might apply.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I wrote this answer as I was figuring things out. If you just want the answer, copy the definitions of `fundQ`, `Ast`, `ksFactors`, `foo`, `makeOneIndex` and `magicJ` out of the code blocks below. You should have

```
DirichletCharacter[d, magicJ[d], n] == KroneckerSymbol[d, n]
```

Disclaimer 1: This answer is based on plausible interpretations of things not quite said in the `DirichletCharacter` documentation and tested for $-120 \leq d \leq 120$. To be sure it's right, you would have to actually look inside `DirichletCharacter` or find better documentation.

Disclaimer 2: $\newcommand{\KS}[2]{\left( \frac{#1}{#2} \right)}$ The set up of this question assumes that $d$ is a fundamental discriminant. I really need that. For $s$ odd, we have $\KS{-1}{2^b s} = (-1)^{(s-1)/2}$, so $\KS{-1}{n}$ is not periodic in $n$, and `DirichletCharacter[k,j,n]` is always periodic modulo $k$. So not all Kronecker symbols can be expressed as Dirichlet characters. Fortunately, the fundamental discriminants can. If you run `magicJ[]` on something which is not a fundamental discriminant, it objects. If you run the internal helper functions on something which is not a fundamental discriminant, I make no promises as to what will happen.

---

Here is a function to test whether $d$ is a fundamental discriminant:

```
fundQ[d_] := Switch[Mod[d, 4], 1, SquareFreeQ[d], 
                      0, SquareFreeQ[d/4] && (Mod[d/4, 4] == 2 || Mod[d/4, 4] == 3), 
                      _,  False]

discs = Select[Range[-120, 120], fundQ]
(* Out={-120, -119, -116, -115, -111, -107, -104, -103, -95, -91, -88, -87,  
        -84, -83, -79, -71, -68, -67, -59, -56, -55, -52, -51, -47, -43, -40, 
        -39, -35, -31, -24, -23, -20, -19, -15, -11, -8, -7, -4, -3, 1, 5, 8, 
         12, 13, 17, 21, 24, 28, 29, 33, 37, 40, 41, 44, 53, 56, 57, 60, 61, 
         65, 69, 73, 76, 77, 85, 88, 89, 92, 93, 97, 101, 104, 105, 109, 113, 120}
```

For any odd prime $p$, define $p^{\ast} = (-1)^{(p-1)/2} p$. Let $d = u 2^b (p_1^{\ast})^{a_1} (p_2^{\ast})^{a_2} \cdots (p_r^{\ast})^{a_r}$ with $u = \pm 1$ and $p_i$ distinct odd primes listed in increasing order. If $d$ is a fundamental discriminant then all the $a_i$ are $1$ and $u 2^b$ is one of $1$, $-4$, $8$ or $8$ so we will assume this from now on.

Here is some code to perform the above computations

```
 Ast[p_] := (-1)^((p-1)/2) p;

 ksFactors[d_] := 
   If[fundQ[d], Module[{facts = FactorInteger[d], primes},
         primes =Map[Ast, Select[Map[First, facts], (# != -1 && # != 2)&]];
         Prepend[primes, d/Product[p, {p, primes}]]], 
      "Error: Not a fundamental discriminant"]

   ksFactors[120]
   (* Out={-8,-3,5} *)
```

Then we have 
$$\KS{d}{n} = \KS{u 2^b}{n} \prod \KS{p_i^{\ast}}{n}^{a_i}$$

For any odd prime $p$, the character $\KS{p^{\ast}}{n}$ is the unique nontrivial real Dirichlet character modulo $|p|$. According to the documentation, the real characters modulo $p$ will be in positions $1$ and $\phi(p)/2+1$, and the one in position $1$ will be trivial.

Actually, the documentation (version 8) says "Real Dirichlet characters modulo k have index $1$ or $\phi(k)/2+1$", which would seem to say that those are the only two real Dirichlet characters. That can't be true since, in many cases, there are more than two real Dirichlet characters. However, it does appear to be true that the characters in those positions are always real.

In any case, when $p$ is prime, there is only one nontrivial real Dirichlet character, namely $\KS{p^{\ast}}{n}$, and it appears in index $\phi(p)/2+1$. Also, for $p$ prime, $\phi(p)/2+1$ simplifies to $(p+1)/2$. Let's check that we're right so far:

```
Table[KroneckerSymbol[Ast[p], Range[4p]] == DirichletCharacter[p,(p+1)/2,Range[4p]], 
         {p,Prime[Range[2,20]]}]]

(* Out = {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

Now, let's deal with the $\KS{u 2^b}{n}$ term. By trial and error, I found

```
KroneckerSymbol[1,n]==DirichletCharacter[1,1,n]
KroneckerSymbol[-4,n]==DirichletCharacter[4,2,n]
KroneckerSymbol[-8, n] == DirichletCharacter[8, 4, n]
KroneckerSymbol[8, n] == DirichletCharacter[8, 2, n]
```

Let's define a function to handle what we know so far

```
foo[x_] :=
    If[PrimeQ[Abs[x]] && Mod[x, 4] == 1, {Abs[x], (Abs[x] + 1)/2}];
foo[1] = {1, 1};
foo[-4] = {4, 2};
foo[-8] = {8, 4};
foo[8] = {8, 2};

map[foo, ksFactors[120]]
(* Out = {{8, 4}, {3, 2}, {5, 3}} *)

thing1 = Table[DirichletCharacter[8, 4, n]*DirichletCharacter[3, 2, n]*DirichletCharacter[5, 3, n], {n, 1, 120}];

thing2 = KroneckerSymbol[120, Range[120]];

thing1 == thing2
(* Out = True *)
```

We now need to combine all of those `DirichletCharacter`s into a single term.

Look at the documentation of `DirichletCharacter` and scroll down to the portion of Properties and Relations beginning "A character modulo $k$ can be written as a product of characters modulo prime powers...". I've cut off the last bit of the quote because it is misleading; they say "prime powers of $k$" but they mean "prime power factors of $k$".

The documentation doesn't quite say the following, but it appears to be true: If $d=\prod_{i=1}^r p_i^{a_i}$, where the $p_i$ are primes listed in increasing order, and
$$j = 1+\sum_{i=1}^r (j_i-1) \cdot  \phi\left( \prod_{k=i+1}^r p_i^{a_i} \right)$$
then `DirichletCharacter[d,j,n]` is the product of the terms `DirichletCharacter[p[i]^a[i], j[i],n]`.

Let's write some code to do this:

```
makeOneIndex[jList_] :=
  1 + Sum[
    (Last[jList[[i]]] - 1)*
    EulerPhi[Product[
       First[jList[[k]]], 
    {k, i + 1, Length[jList]}]], 
 {i, 1, Length[jList]}]

 magicJ[d_]:=
    If[fundQ[d], makeOneIndex[Map[foo, ksFactors[d]]], "Not a fundamental discriminant"]
```

And let's test it:

```
Table[DirichletCharacter[d, magicJ[d], Range[d]] == KroneckerSymbol[d, Range[d]], {d, discs}]

 (* Out = {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for putting the time into this; I really appreciate it!